# bash: pruning all but a prefix matching a glob (and extension) from a filename

Tags: bash

I am trying to rename all files using `bash` that are a specific extension `.bam`.

**files before renaming**

```
IonXpress_001_R_2016_02_11_11_51_07_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_Auto_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_84.bam
IonXpress_002_R_2016_02_11_11_51_07_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_Auto_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_84.bam
IonXpress_003_R_2016_02_11_11_51_07_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_Auto_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_84.bam
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_001.vcf
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_002.vcf
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_003.vcf
```

**desired output after renaming**

```
IonXpress_001.bam
IonXpress_002.bam
IonXpress_003.bam
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_001.vcf
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_002.vcf
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_003.vcf
```

**bash loop**

```
for file in *.bam
do
mv "$file" "${file/*_*.bam/*_.bam}"
done
```

Comment: BTW, for a more general answer, BashFAQ #30 is apropos: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030 -- some of the items in the "nonstandard tools" sections are regex-based, and thus can easily be used for this question.

Comment: Is there always a letter after the second underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `_R_` is constant, easy to take advantage of it:

```
for file in *.bam; do
  mv -- "$file" "${file%%_R_*}.bam"
done
```

Otherwise, a one can end up with something like this:

```
for file in *.bam; do
  suffix=${file#*_*_}         # calculate what's left after trimming the parts we want
  prefix=${file%"_$suffix"}   # strip that remainder off the tail of the original filename
  mv -- "$file" "$prefix.bam" # ...and substitute what's left
done
```

---

To explain how this works, the [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) documentation will be an invaluable guide. However, the process can be summarized thus:

- `${file#*_*_}` does a non-greedy (matching as little as possible) match **deleting** content starting from the beginning of `$file`, including the first two underscores and content preceeding them. Thus, the result is something like `suffix=_R_2016_02_11_11_51_07_user_Proton-etc-etc.bam`.
- `prefix=${file%"_$suffix"}` takes the original filename, and removes that suffix from the end, leaving only the prefix at the beginning that we want to keep. (Quoting it ensures that the string is treated as literal content, rather than a glob-style pattern).

Comment: BTW, my first answer could be buggy if the filename contained components which could be treated as a glob; see the quoting changes in the edit.